# Best practices for SQLite DB and ContentProvider

Tags: android, orm

My Android app is reading and writing to a local SQLite DB from a few different Activities and a Service. Pretty standard. But I'm not happy with the way I've got all the DB details stored as constants that I then use anywhere I access the DB. I've been advised to wrap the DB in a ContentProvider. Sounds good to me. While I'm refactoring my code, I figured I'd ask:

- What are your best practices for local DB data storage in Android?
- Where and how do you store "CREATE TABLE" statements, column names, other SQL?
- Would you mind sharing a list of the classes you instantiate and what goes into each (ContentProvider, DatabaseProvider, DatabaseHelper...)?
- How do you coordinate the structure of your local Android DB with a server-side DB available through a REST interface?

Yeah, I realize I'm getting at the perennial "where's the Android object-relation-mapping framework?" question. For now, I'm mainly curious to hear how you structure your Android apps with what's available in the standard SDK.

As always, thanks for the pointers!

Comment: On a tongue-in-cheek note, here's the one relevant video from the Android Dev site: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i293O69nuRo

Comment: Exactly the question i was going to ask! Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We have been tuning [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) on Android for a while now and it is working well.  ORMLite supports Android with native database calls and also supports other databases via JDBC.  You annotate your classes/fields and use base DAO classes to persist to SQLite.

- CREATE TABLE statements are handled my ORMLite's utility classes.  Most SQL is taken care of by the DAO classes.
- The Android section of the [online documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/ormlite.html) explains the class hierarchy.  You implement a `DatabaseHelper` which helps create an update your database.  Your activities extend `OrmLiteBaseActivity` (or service or tab) which gives access to helper and DAOs.
- ORMLite does not provide a solution for merging with remote REST servers.

Hope this is somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> For now, I'm mainly curious to hear how you structure your Android apps with what's available in the standard SDK.

I'm not a real fan of SQL and the way that it's handled in android, so I use the object database [NeoDatis](http://www.neodatis.org/). It basically just lets you store / retrieve Java objects into a flat file stored on the device very easily.  db40 is also another alternative Object Database that will work on android.

Haven't had any issues using this approach, you may want to note that including the NeoDatis library will increase your APK size by ~700kb.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I have an answer, other than I don't really like how this is handled, I find it very messy as well.  I usually follow the pattern given in the notepad example that comes w/ the SDK.

Due to this I am working on my own mini ORM framework, using annotation and managing all of this.  So far things are working ok, but I haven't worked everything out yet.

Comment: Yeah, I should actually step through the entire notepad tutorial. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at [Androrm](http://androrm.com). It is an open source orm tool designed espacially for android. It should help you with all database related stuff.

Comment: Terrible doco for this one though. Dont even try to submit a bug or feature request...

Comment: What is so terrible about www.androrm.com/documentation ? And have you ever tried to submit feedback?

Comment: Yes I have tried to. I had to sign up to some silly community thing which then didnt even have an option to contact anyone or leave a forum post. Ended up as a huge waste of time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added contact email to both the documentation and the contribution page and also a quick description of phabricator.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the list more and more ... Another ORM is the ORM solution provided with the [BARACUS Framework](http://www.baracus.org). It is not inteded to build enterprise sized databases, its more for storing a couple of entities in the database and make it accessible by the app. There is no codegeneration approach inside of it; you simply write your entity pojo, a rowmapper and your table def. Therefore you can make use of DAOs, Dependency Injection, IOC style lifecycle support and much more.

ORM Features so far :

- [Lazy Loading (Collections + Lazy References)](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2013/10/baracus-from-scratch-part-5-advanced.html)
- [CRUD operations for free](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2013/10/baracus-from-scratch-part-3-persistence.html)
- Query by example
- a couple of aspects (autotimestamp etc)
- [Persistence layer lifecycle support across multiple application releases](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2014/03/baracus-from-scratch-part-7-android.html)

For the more sophisticated database stuff (using the ORM is a little bit hand work like in good old spring rowmapper time) I am currently thinking about adding ormlite integration.

For more code details just check the [tutorial application on github](https://github.com/gorefest/baracus-tutorial)